# A list of the possible web api shipping method codes for the salesOrderRepositoryV1 GET?

Tags: magento-2.1, api, shipping-methods, webapi

I am using Magento 2.1.0 web api system to extract new orders from my Magento store and then place them into a 3rd party accounting system. I would like to know what are all of the possible responses for the shipping method.

One of the fields in the `salesOrderRepositoryV1` response gives what the customer's selected shipping method is for their order. For example it would output `{ ups_3ds }` to represent the customer selecting *UPS 3 day shipping* for their order. What are the other codes for the shipping method field (for example what is the code for *UPS ground shipping*, *UPS Next day shipping*, etc)

A link to the response schema of the `salesOrderRepositoryV1` can be found [here](http://devdocs.magento.com/swagger/)

**Edited** I am not sure how much more detail I can give you all

```
"shipping": {
      "address": {
        "address_type": "string",
        "city": "string",
        "company": "string",
        "country_id": "string",
        "customer_address_id": 0,
        "customer_id": 0,
        "email": "string",
        "entity_id": 0,
        "fax": "string",
        "firstname": "string",
        "lastname": "string",
        "middlename": "string",
        "parent_id": 0,
        "postcode": "string",
        "prefix": "string",
        "region": "string",
        "region_code": "string",
        "region_id": 0,
        "street": [
          "string"
        ],
        "suffix": "string",
        "telephone": "string",
        "vat_id": "string",
        "vat_is_valid": 0,
        "vat_request_date": "string",
        "vat_request_id": "string",
        "vat_request_success": 0,
        "extension_attributes": {}
      },
      "method": "string",
      "total": {
        "base_shipping_amount": 0,
        "base_shipping_canceled": 0,
        "base_shipping_discount_amount": 0,
        "base_shipping_discount_tax_compensation_amnt": 0,
        "base_shipping_incl_tax": 0,
        "base_shipping_invoiced": 0,
        "base_shipping_refunded": 0,
        "base_shipping_tax_amount": 0,
        "base_shipping_tax_refunded": 0,
        "shipping_amount": 0,
        "shipping_canceled": 0,
        "shipping_discount_amount": 0,
        "shipping_discount_tax_compensation_amount": 0,
        "shipping_incl_tax": 0,
        "shipping_invoiced": 0,
        "shipping_refunded": 0,
        "shipping_tax_amount": 0,
        "shipping_tax_refunded": 0,
        "extension_attributes": {}
      },
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to Magento SE. Your question is unclear. What is your exact question here? What do you need? Why do you need it? What does the code you pasted mean? Where did you get it from? What do you need it do do?

Comment: Thank you for the additional information. I'll vote to reopen the question.

Comment: Why was this closed?

Comment: Because the question was unclear at first. After you have edited the question I thought it would be clear and I voted for it to be reopened again. However other members of the Magento SE did not also vote to reopen, so unfortunately it remains closed.

Comment: I appreciate your explanation but could your other members explain what is still confusing? It seems hypocritical to close a question for not enough information and then give an explanation with not enough information.

Comment: At the very least keep it open for other members of the community to hopefully provide their two cents about the question.  If no one responds in a month or so. Then close the question.